# Variables in awk inside a for loop

Tags: bash, ubuntu, variables, awk

I have a problem in my bash script.

```
for b in O B A F G K M
do   
u='$n'$b  
w='$m'$b  
awk -v "j=$u" -v "h=$b" 'BEGIN{printf(" "h" stars: %6d  ", j)}'  
awk -v "i=$w" 'BEGIN{printf("%"i"s\n", "[]")}' | sed 's/ /[]/g'  
done
```

I need to use variables called "nO" then "nB" etc in awk. My teacher suggested assigning values of these to another variables before awk, but when I do this it just prints "$nO" instead of its value like "200". How to do this? I need something like: awk -v j=$[n$b], so j is assigned the value of variable nO in first loop, then the value of nB. (These nO or mO are already defined earlier.

Comment: Defined where? [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). It seems like this is not about awk at all: is `nO` a _shell_ variable?

Comment: Assume it just exists, I defined nO, nB, nA etc variables before, now i just want to use them in awk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have `nO=200`, you can use `b=O` in `u="n$b"`, and get the value

```
awk -v "j=${!u}" -v "h=$b" 'BEGIN{printf(" "h" stars: %6d  ", j)}'
```

The `!` will look up the variable it references to.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use a "nameref" (introduces in bash 4.3)

```sh
nB=Hello mB=World
letter=B

declare -n u="n$letter" w="m$letter"

awk -v j="$u" -v h="$w" 'BEGIN {print "j is " j; print "h is " h}'
```

```
j is Hello
h is World
```

---

or, restructure your shell script to use an associative array (bash 4.0):

```sh
declare -A n m
n[B]=foo
m[B]=bar
letter=B

awk -v j="${n[$letter]}" -v h="${m[$letter]}" 'BEGIN {print "j is " j; print "h is " h}'
```